# raise exception wave python

Tags: python, exception, wave

I use the wave module
for  example .

```
     import wave
     origAudio = wave.open("son.wav",'r')
```

get output

```
       raise Error, 'file does not start with RIFF id'
       wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id
```

I know the file is not good,but I want to raise this exception or this error

Comment: The exception 'Error' has already been raised for you. Do you mean catch and reraise a different one?

Comment: @RedX I want the program continues to turn after this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to continue after an expection has been raised you must catch it:

```
 import wave
 try:
   origAudio = wave.open("son.wav",'r')
 except wave.Error as e:
   # if you get here it means an error happende, maybe you should warn the user
   # but doing pass will silently ignore it
   pass
```

Comment: It probably is `wave.Error`. See the updated answer.